# How to display decimals on Kusto

Tags: kql

I have this code

```
| extend missing_time_hours = (missing_time_minutes / 60)
```

which is basically dividing 171/60 and giving me 2 as a result.

The issue is that I want 2.85 as my result, not 2.
How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
| extend missing_time_hours = (missing_time_minutes / 60.0)
```